# How do I get or create associated token accounts with the wallet adapter?

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm trying to send SPL tokens to a specific address using a Wallet Adapter.
Also I need to create an associated account for recipient, but the `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` @solana/spl-token method requires a keypair.

So, I need to sign the transaction through the Wallet Adapter:

1. Sender's find or create ATA
2. Recipient's find or create ATA
3. createTransferInstruction

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get or create an associated token account with the wallet-adapter, you need to use the underlying source of `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount`

```
const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint,
    owner,
    allowOwnerOffCurve,
    programId,
    associatedTokenProgramId
);

let account: Account;
try {
    account = await getAccount(connection, associatedToken, commitment, programId);
} catch (error: unknown) {
  if (error instanceof TokenAccountNotFoundError || error instanceof TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError) {
    try {
      const transaction = new Transaction().add(
          createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
              publicKey,
              associatedToken,
              owner,
              mint,
              programId,
              associatedTokenProgramId
          )
      );

      await sendTransaction(connection, transaction);
    } catch (error: unknown) {
    }
    account = await getAccount(connection, associatedToken, commitment, programId);
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
return account;
```

The above code adapts the [source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/118bd047aa0f1ba1930b5bc4639d40aa2a375ccb/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L46) in `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` to uses the `sendTransaction` and `publicKey` from `useWallet` in the wallet-adapter to use whatever wallet the user has chosen.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I want to clarify, is it possible to combine a transaction into one and use one confirmation from the Wallet Adapter if the ATA is not created?

Now if I send a token to an empty address, I first confirm the creation of the ATA, wait a few seconds for the account to be found, and then a second confirmation occurs from the Wallet Adapter to send the token.

Comment: @Kanitelk yes, with multiple instructions, you can create the ATA in the same transaction as the transfer.